# Saving diffs to two files for modified and new additions

Tags: text-processing, command-line, diff

I'm trying to compare a new file (e.g., `new.txt`) to an old file (e.g., `old.txt`) to see what was added in the new file. I'm trying to add the newly added information to a new file called `newCourses.txt` and the modified information to `modifiedCourses.txt`. If this is not possible with a diff, what are the alternatives without installing a package or software?

`old.txt`

```
2016 2BUSI 4850 K002 BUSINESS MW 02:10P-09:30P
2016 2BUSI 4840 K002 PRESPECH MW 07:10P-09:30P
2016 2BUSI 4820 K002 SCHLOFSC MW 07:10P-09:30P
2016 2BUSI 4870 K002 HISTORYZ MW 04:10P-09:30P
```

`new.txt`

```
2016 2BUSI 4850 K002 BUSINESS MW 07:10P-09:30P
2016 2BUSI 4840 K002 PRESPECH MW 07:10P-09:30P
2016 2BUSI 4820 K002 SCHLOFSC MF 07:10P-09:30P
2016 2BUSI 4870 K002 HISTORYZ MW 06:10P-09:30P
2017 4NONE 2938 K112 RECREATI TS 11:10P-11:55P
```

The output when I do `diff old.txt new.txt`:

```
1c1
< 2016 2BUSI 4850 K002 BUSINESS MW 02:10P-09:30P
---
> 2016 2BUSI 4850 K002 BUSINESS MW 07:10P-09:30P
3,4c3,5
< 2016 2BUSI 4820 K002 SCHLOFSC MW 07:10P-09:30P
< 2016 2BUSI 4870 K002 HISTORYZ MW 04:10P-09:30P
\ No newline at end of file
---
> 2016 2BUSI 4820 K002 SCHLOFSC TF 07:10P-09:30P
> 2016 2BUSI 4870 K002 HISTORYZ MW 06:10P-09:30P
> 2017 4NONE 2938 K112 RECREATI TS 11:10P-11:55P
\ No newline at end of file
```

How can I output it to two different files such as
`newCourses.txt` would contain

```
2017 4NONE 2938 K112 RECREATI TS 11:10P-11:55P
```

and `modifiedCourses.txt` would contain

```
2016 2BUSI 4850 K002 BUSINESS MW 07:10P-09:30P
2016 2BUSI 4820 K002 SCHLOFSC TF 07:10P-09:30P
2016 2BUSI 4870 K002 HISTORYZ MW 06:10P-09:30P
```

Comment: (1) Please use examples that are easier to read. (2) You might want to devise clearer filenames, too. You have old file, new file, a new file and modified.txt; so, if I say “the new file”, it might be misunderstood. (3) Will there ever be deletions or *insertions* (lines added other than at the end)?  If not, are you happy with saying that, if the old file is 4 lines long (as in your example), then the first 4 lines of the new file are either changes or unchanged lines, and everything from the 5th line to the end is an addition?  Otherwise, how do you distinguish between changes and additions?

Comment: @don_crissti Yes the first 5 columns stay the same.

Comment: @Scott made it easier to read. I'm assuming to distinguish from changes and additions I would match based on first 5 columns that stay the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{ z[$5]=$0; next}{ if ($5 in z){ if ($0!=z[$5]){
print >"modifiedCourses.txt"}} else { print >"newCourses.txt"}}' old.txt new.txt
```

This reads `old.txt` and saves the lines into an array (the indices are the names of the courses) and then reads `new.txt` and for each course it checks if it's an index of the array: if it is, it checks if the line has changed and if so it prints it to `modifiedCourses.txt` ; if not an index, it prints the line to `newCourses.txt`
You can change `$0` to `$7` if the only change that matters is the hours.

Comment: It’s impossible to tell from the sample data, and I do see that the OP accepted this answer, but, from his comments, I believe that you should use `$1$2$3$4$5` as your index.

Comment: @Scott - I'm not sure I understand your comment... Per OP's comment (in reply to a now-deleted-comment of mine) the first 4 fields are always the same for a certain course. So if the course is `BUSINESS` that field will always be preceded by `2016 2BUSI 4850 K002`. Only 6th and/or 7th fields may change. What is the point then to use `$1$2$3$4$5` ? It does no harm but it's superfluous...

Comment: I think you understand my comment just fine, but we’re interpreting the OP’s comment differently.  I asked him, “how do you distinguish between changes and additions?”  I interpret his response to mean, “If line 39 of `old.txt` and line 42 of `new.txt` have the same values in the first five columns, then they are the same line; if they differ in columns 6 and/or 7, then that is a changed line.  If they differ in columns 1-5, then you have a *new line*, and file 2 line 43 might match file 1 line 39.”

Comment: @Scott - 1.  _..."have the same values in the first five columns, then they are the same line"_ no, two lines are the same line _only if_ they are identical (this is not a matter of interpretation btw); 2. here you are right that is _"if they differ in columns 6 and/or 7, then that is a changed line"_; 3. _" If they differ in columns 1-5, then you have a new line"_ again correct but we are only interested in `$5` because - per OPs comment (and examples) - the first 4 fields are always the same for each course name (hence they can be safely ignored).

Comment: This conversation is going nowhere.

Comment: @Scott - :) at least we can agree on something